# Ignore SSL self signed certificate errors Restful httpclient

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have done tons of searching and reading on this, there are so many different ways to achieve this. However, things have changed a bit since a lot of the posts. Ultimately, I am using a UWP (10586 minimum target) app. I have wrapped my httpclient code into a .net standard library which my UWP app consumes. However, because of the 10586 SDK version, my .net standard library must be 1.4 or lower.

I need to post json to a web service in a RESTful way. Tjis web service uses SSL but has a self signed certificate. So, I get certificate errors. I simply want to ignore them so I can make my calls. Using 3rd party web service test utility  (Postman), I have confirmed the calls will work if SSL errors are simply ignored.

Based on my UWP and .net standard setup, I cannot use the X509 namespace to ignore SSL errors. This is one method but X509 is not available.

So, this looked most promising: https://blog.roushtech.net/2016/12/20/ignoring-ssl-certificate-errors-net-core-httpclient/

It has no compiler errors, but at runtime I get a "platform not supported" exception.

Is there any way to work around all of this given my configurations?

EDIT: The exact snippet I am using that seems to be the supported method in the future but gives platform error on UWP is the same in the link I copied above. For reference, this is what I am doing:

```
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
   httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, 
   cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };

   using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
   {
       // Make request here.
   }
}
```

Also, yes my code does work with non ssl (http) calls. It had been working fine for some time until I needed to access a new/different web service which is configured as ssl.

Thanks!!!

Comment: "It has no compiler errors, but at runtime I get a "platform not supported" exception." Some key code snippet please. Did your code snippet can work well if one service has no certificate? Have  you tried `IgnorableServerCertificateErrors
` property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter#Windows_Web_Http_Filters_HttpBaseProtocolFilter_IgnorableServerCertificateErrors

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Thank you for the response. The snippet I tried to use to ignore the certificate is in my update above. Also, I can confirm that the code works perfectly on non ssl web services. It is only when the web service is ssl and has certificate errors that I have an issue, which is what I am trying to ignore. Thanks!